# figuring out value semantics in C++

Tags: c++, memory-leaks

I have a class String with the following members:

```
Class String{
    ...
    private:

    char* word

    int length
}
```

String's copy assignment returns a String& and allocates word on the heap.

I also have a linked list class written in C that has a function:

```
void *popFront(struct List *list)
{
    struct Node prevHead = list->head
    list->head = prevHead->next;
    void *info = prevHead->info;
    free(prevHead);
    return info;
}
```

My task is to write the same function for a C++ linked list that uses the C function. This is what I have:

```
String List::popFront()
{
    String s = (*(String *) ::popFront(&list));//casting the void * to String
    return s;

}
```

The C++ method should return the object by value. That's what I thought the method would do. However, 
I'm getting memory leaks. Any hint on how I need to modify List::popFront() so that it returns by value? Thanks.

Comment: Does String also properly delete word when it is destroyed?

Comment: Yes, and it's also in a class that I can't modify.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`popFront` removes the element from the linked list and frees the node, but not the `info` portion. This is the responsibility of the caller of `popFront`, e.g.

```
String *s = (String *) ::popFront(&list);
delete s;
```

But you must also keep a copy, which you can return from the method

```
String List::popFront()
{
    String *s = (String *) ::popFront(&list);
    String tmp = *s;
    delete s;
    return tmp;
}
```

Comment: Yes!!! I tried using temp, but I'm so exhausted right now after only 4 hours of sleep that I must have done it wrong. But yes, this is brilliant.

Answer (score 1):

First store the returned pointer locally as a pointer to string, then make a local copy of the string, then delete the object, the pointer points to and finally return the local copy.

EDIT:
Btw. you can use c++11's smart pointers to avoid the extra copy:

```
String List::popFront()
{
    auto s = std::unique_ptr<String>((String*) ::popFront(&list));  
    return *s;
}
```

but that is probably not, what your teacher aims at.

Answer (score 0):

You declare `String List::popFront()` which returns an object, not a pointer. And `String s = ...` declares an object, not a pointer or reference. So assigning `s` a value *constructs* a new object `s` being a *copy* of what `::popFront` returned, then a next *copy* of `s` is returned and `s` itself gets destroyed. However the object unlinked by `::popFront()` remains on a heap, making a leak.

Don't create an intermediate copy of `String` object, return the pointer to unlinked object, so that a caller can link it to its own list or `delete` it after use:

```
String *List::popFront()
{
    String *s = (String *) ::popFront(&list);//casting the void * to String *
    return s;
}
```

Comment: Wasn`t the task to return an object by value?

Comment: Yes, unfortunately, the method has to return by value, and I can't modify the provided tester class.